# Express - using application-level middleware conditionally on route-level

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to understand how to use an application-level middleware (or at least usually used like this) like `cookie-parser` on  route-level and conditionally.

I tried something like:

```
const myMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
 if (myCondition) {
   return cookieParser();
 } else {
   next();
 }
}

app.use('/admin', myMiddleware, (req, res) => {
 res.sendStatus(401)
})
```

But it's not working, the request will be just stuck.

Is this possible?

Traditional `cookie-parser` implementation:

```
app.use(cookieParser())
```

Comment: Your middleware fails to call next in one of those branches.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I literally mean in one of the two conditional branches in your middleware, you do not call next. That's why the request hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cookieParser()` returns a [middleware function](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), i.e. a function that takes in `req, res, next` as arguments. You just have to pass it the arguments:

```
const cookieParserMiddleware = cookieParser();

const myMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  if (myCondition) {
    return cookieParserMiddleware(req, res, next);
  }

  next();
};

app.use("/admin", myMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(401);
});
```

Notice that I'm creating the cookieParser middleware outside `myMiddleware` - technically we could also just do `return cookieParser()(req, res, next)` but recreating the same middleware again and again on every request would be wasteful.

I've also removed the `else` since the `if` block `return`s from the function ([guard clause](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html)).